# Reset link background color on previously selected

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a song playlist & use javascript in the player to set the back ground color to light green on the playing song. I am aware I could use a:focus however if the user selects the lyrics while the song is playing the song will continue to play however it looses focus so the background color reverts to original. I need a way to use javascript to change the color of the song back to its original when the song is no longer playing or another song is selected. code below.

```
<!-- Video Player Script -->


var video_playlist = document.getElementById("video_player");
var links = video_playlist.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {                 
    links[i].onclick = handler;                       
};

function handler(e) {                               
    e.preventDefault();     
    videotarget = this.getAttribute("href");
    filename = videotarget.substr(0, videotarget.lastIndexOf('.')) || videotarget;
    video = document.querySelector("#video_player video");
    source = document.querySelectorAll("#video_player video source");
    source[0].src = filename + ".mp3";
    video.load();   
    video.play();   
    this.style.background = "#AAFF8D";                  
};
```

Comment: Just a note, Java is not short for JavaScript, it's a completely different language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scouring google & some playing came up with the answer.

Thank you goes out to Spencer Wieczorek & Walker Boh for answers I thought should work.

Code Below:

```
<!-- Video Player Script -->


<!-- Get Selected Link --> 
var video_playlist = document.getElementById("video_player");
var links = video_playlist.getElementsByTagName('a');   
**var ele = video_playlist.getElementsByTagName("a");
var activeEle = null;**

for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++)
{                
links[i].onclick = handler;
};


<!-- Find Previously Selected Link -->
**for( var i=0; i<ele.length; i++ ) 
{
if( ele.item(i).style.background == "##AAFF8D" )
{
document.write(ele.item(i).id);
break;
}
}**

<!-- Highlight Selected Link & Remove Highlght On Previous Link -->             
**function highlight( )
{ 
if (activeEle){
activeEle.style.background = "#F9F9F9";
}                               
var oObj = event.currentTarget;
oObj.style.background = "#AAFF8D"; 
activeEle = oObj;
}** 


function handler(e)
{   
e.preventDefault();     
videotarget = this.getAttribute("href");
filename = videotarget.substr(0, videotarget.lastIndexOf('.')) ||
videotarget;
video = document.querySelector("#video_player video");
source = document.querySelectorAll("#video_player video source");                   
source[0].src = filename + ".mp3";
video.load();   
video.play();   
**highlight();**
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is an html5 video then use the onended proptery to detect when the video finishes playing:

```
video.onended = function(e) {
  // change background color here
};
```

Comment: You too :) Interesting that both the comments are the same.

Comment: Same as above no joy using this code, place in the actual function and outside with no results.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using a `<video>` for the music. With that in mind by "song is no longer playing." I'm going to assume that means the video has ended. In that case you can have an event `onended` that will change the background color to the original:

```
var player = document.getElementById("video_player");
player.onended = function(){
    // Change background color here
};
```

Comment: We answered practically at the same time and with the same answer. Have an upvote!

Comment: You are correct I am using a video player to do both audio & video. Tried every combination I can think of with your code and could not get it to work.

Comment: @Mike Did you place code within the comment? For example, to test it place an `alert("test")`, and it should show up at the end of the video.